# How can I say this in sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I have

```
text text text [text text] \n
text text text [text text] \n
```

I want

```
text text text \n
text text text \n
```

What RE can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works regardless of whether the `\n` is the end of line or a backslash and a letter 'n':

```
sed 's/\[.*] //' $file
```

The pattern looks for an open square bracket followed by any sequence of characters up to the last close square bracket and a following space (if there are several).  You could refine the '`.*`' into '`[^]]*`' to match anything that is not a close square bracket; this only deletes to the first close square bracket.

Answer (score 2):

`/[^\[]*/` gets you most of the way.  If nothing ever appears after [...], then it is sufficient.

Comment: The OP may want to add a space on one end or th'other of that regex, if spaces are interesting.

Comment: Can you explain what else you're going to do with that RE?  It matches a pattern of 'anything but backslash or open square bracket', so you have some work to do to use it in a substitute operation, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk

```
$ more file
text [dont want text here ] text text [ dont want text] \n
text text text [ dont want text] \n

$ awk -vRS=']'  '/\[/{gsub(/\[.*/,"")}1' ORS="" file
text  text text  \n
text text text  \n
```